# Python directory structure for a package featuring a FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, python-packaging

I am using the following directory structure when create a Python project :

```
├─ src
│  └─ packagename
│     ├─ __init__.py
│     └─ ...
├─ tests
│  └─ ...
└─ setup.py
```

This is taken from this [site](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/).

Now, I am learning to create API, using the FastAPI package. And I am at a loss regarding the location where I should put the API. I would like to have an `api.py` Python file where I would code the API.

Or maybe in the future I would like to use a structure like this one :

```
├── app
│   │── env
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api.py
│   └── src
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── user
│   │   │    ├── __init__.py
│   │   │    └── api.py
│   │   │
│   │   └── item
│   │         ├── __init__.py
│   │         └── api.py
```

Note that there is a key difference with my structure : all folders feature a `__init__.py` file. And this is crucial because in FastAPI tutorials, they usually test the api with such command :

```
uvicorn app.apy:app --reload
```

so it requires that every directory is in fact a python package/module and therefore features a `__init__.py` file.

I know why I want to use my structure (and this is stated in the link provided) : *import parity*. It forces you to actually install the package and test that it works. Wheras if you don't have a `src` directory, given that your current directory is implicitely added to the ´sys.path´, your code may work on your machine but fails when someone tries to install it because of missing dependencies or an incorrect package.

Now what I want to know and I am not knowledgeable enough in Python to know that : does adding a `__init__.py` to every level in my structure could cause an issue given the intent ? Could it allow "cheating" locally and therefore missing problems in deployment ?

Thanks !